# Catching exceptions thrown by class functions

Tags: c++, exception

I'm trying to implement exception handling in a workout tracker program i created that currently has no error checking. I have a `Exlist` class that handles a linked list a series of functions, some important functions i would like at add exception handling:

- Update list into text file
- Sort list by dates
- Edit workout(searches list using key)
- Delete workout(searches list using key to delete)
- Add workout

How would i go about throwing exceptions from a function inside a class and catching them in int `main()`. i know of simple exception handing in the same block, but i can't seem to conjure up a solution to solving this. My ideal situation would be

```
//in int main, when the user selects add
try
{
    WorkoutList.addEx();
} 
//other code...
//catch at end of loop and display error
catch(string error)
{
    cout << "Error in: addEx..." << error << endl;
}
```

Comment: Is there anything not working with the code you presented?

Comment: Do not throw `std::string` objects! You should throw only objects of classes derived from `std::exception`. Although you can throw any copyable class, catching random classes makes it much harder to determine what happened. Catching `std::exception const&` and having a look at the `what()` member gives at least some hint on what went on.

Comment: This is what precisely exceptions are for! Just throw them wherever, and they 'bubble up' until they're caught, destructing objects that go out of scope as they go.

Comment: The functions you listed that seem like they should throw are the ones involving text files and "Add workout".

Comment: @DietmarKühl: I would change the wording slightly to `derived from std::runtime_error (or one of its derived classes)` rather than `std::exception`. The reason is that std::runtime_error can be constructed with an error message while std::exception can't (unless it was updated in C++11).

Comment: @LokiAstari: Agreed. The fundamental commonality is, however, that the objects thrown are derived from `std::exception` and `std::runtime_error` (or classes derived thereof) is one potential choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an exception class which inherits from Exception. For example, if you want to throw it when a wrong value is added, you could do:

```
#include <stdexcept>
class WrongValueException : public std::runtime_error
{
    public:
        WrongValueException(string mess): std::runtime_error(mess) {}
};
```

Then, in the `addEx()` function, throw it

```
//SomeCode
if(value.isWrong()){
    throw WrongValueException("Wrong Value");
} else {
    //add
}
```

And catch it in the main:

```
int main(){
    //SomeCode
    try
    {
         WorkoutList.addEx();
    } 
    //other code...
    //catch at end of loop and display error
    catch(WrongValueException const& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << "WrongValueException: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch(std::exception const& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << "std::exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        throw;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Unknown Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        throw;
    }
```

The thrown exception will bubble from wherever you throw it until it gets caught. If it is not caught, the program will finish (potentially without unwinding the stack (thus it is usally best to always catch exceptions in main (to force stack unwinding) even if you re-throw).